# If I host my web app in AWS Do I have to use S3

Tags: php, aws-sdk

I have a web application that store images and Videos.im using PHP.is it make sense if I use S3 instead of store in file server since both are in AWS ( web server and file storage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I would strongly recommend. S3 is an object storage service provided by AWS. It is a good place to store static files like images/videos/css/javascript which you can serve directly without putting more load on your servers. There are many benefits if you use S3,

1. 99.999999999% durability and 99.99% availability of your files
2. Scalability on demand
3. Provide file caching support with the integration of CloudFront - Load Files much faster
4. Granular access management of the files
5. Private content distribution with [CloudFront Signed URls](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html)
6. Stream media with CloudFront to viewers across the globe
7. Ability to protect data with [encryption](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/serv-side-encryption.html) easily (eg: SSE-S3, SSE-KMS)
8. Lifecycle management of your files eg: archiving at low cost
9. Easy set up of disaster recovery with Cross Region Replication of the files

You may use [AWS SDK for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/) to interact with S3 from your server.

Comment: Yes I used php sdk.the problem I have is to upload files to S3 first I have to upload to local server and from ther I have to to upload to S3.Is it double work..?just as an example think I have to upload a video and have to get a preview once it upload.its very time consuming.what is the solution for these kind of problems using S3..? If I'm doing it wrong what is the correct way of doing..?

Comment: If you upload a large file via server it could cause a performance issue. Have a look at the following article addressing this problem. 
https://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2015/direct-upload-to-s3-using-aws-signature-v4-php/

Answer (score 0):

First of all its not a must to host files in S3 if you use AWS but strongly recommended for Static Files that doesn't change frequently like Videos, Images, JS, CSS & etc.

If you use S3 for file storage, you can leverage all the benefits of reliability and performance efficiency which comes default by S3.

Also its recommended to use Event Driven Patterns for file uploads to S3 and storing metadata of files, which will increase the scalability of your application. Following [example](http://blog.michaelschmatz.com/2016/04/02/how-to-build-an-image-host-using-aws-lambda-s3-and-dynamo/) illustrates a typical flow for file uploads and storing file metadata in DynamoDB with S3 event triggers.

[image]

For frequent modification of files or partial updates you can use different storage options like [Elastic File System](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) or [EBS](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/).

For both approaches you can gain higher read speeds by caching the content through AWS CloudFront CDN.